# Xamarin Forms binding button Command to parent BindingContext

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I'm writing Xamarin application and I found difference between WPF which I cannot cross.

I'm using Xamarin Forms Labs to get Repeater control.

I have a Repeater, which repeats DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Button Text="{Binding Text}" Command="{Binding CategorySelectedCommand}"  />
</DataTemplate>
```

But i would like to move command execution to my userControl Binding Context.

Normally with WPF it would look like:

```
Command={Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=DataContext.CategorySelectedCommand}
```

But it does not have ElementName property.

I have found that I could set BindingContext of my button like this:

```
BindingContext="{x:Reference myUserControl}"
```

But then I cannot bind Text property to my button's text.

How should I do this?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?  It seems `Source` doesn't work with a DataTemplate.  It's a real shame too, makes it difficult to do real MVVM.

Comment: Nevermind.  I was behind on updates.  This seems to be working now.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `Source` property to specify a source for the binding that will be used instead of the current `BindingContext`. Then the text can come from the page's binding context and the command from somewhere else.

```
Command="{Binding CategorySelectedCommand, Source={x:Static me:SomeStaticClass.YourUserControl}}"
```

or

```
Command="{Binding CategorySelectedCommand, Source={DynamicResource yourUserControlKey}}"
```

or

```
Command="{Binding CategorySelectedCommand, Source={x:Reference myUserControl}}"
```

Here's a complete example. A common problem is to not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and set the property *after* the call to `InitializeComponent()`.

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="test.MyPage" x:Name="ThePage">
    <Label Text="{Binding TextProp, Source={x:Reference ThePage}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</ContentPage>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage ()
    {
        this.TextProp = "Some Text";
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    public string TextProp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a `ContentPage` with x:Name `wireframe`. In ViewModel of this page I have property `MainText`.

Then in DataTemplate I have Label:
`<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference wireframe}, Path=MainText}"></Label>`

And it does not work. I have tried also `Path=BindingContext.MainText`. No success

Comment: Is the property public?

Comment: This seems to work only if my control is a child of ContentView etc. If i'm using DataTemplate it does not work