# Xamarin XAML Commands Not Firing

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin XAML content page, on which are a bunch of buttons. The intention is for these buttons to execute commands which I have currently coded into my ViewModel.

The problem is, the commands are not firing. I have set breakpoints inside my void methods which are linked all the way up to my constructor. The constructor is working OK. When I click the button the breakpoint doesn't get hit in my task that executes the process.

The binding of the viewmodel works OK because other data is bound to the page OK.

Specifically, the void methods DeleteScan and DeleteTiming are the ones I am trying to get working first.

Incidentally, I have similar code working in another view successfully but I can't work out whats wrong with this view/viewmodel.

Any ideas?

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="TechsportiseApp.Views.ResultsProcess" x:Name="ParentView" Title="Processing">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" Padding="2" IsVisible="{Binding Error}">
            <Label Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color="#80000000"/>
        <Label Text="Validation messages can go here" TextColor="Red" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="{Binding Invalid}" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="3" IsVisible = "{Binding AddVisibility}">
            <Button x:Name="buttonAddScan" Style="{StaticResource Buttons}"  Image="addmanual.png"  Text="Add Finisher"  IsVisible="{Binding AddVisibility}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />       
            <Button x:Name="buttonAddTime" Style="{StaticResource Buttons}"  Image="addmanual.png" Text="Add Time"  IsVisible="{Binding AddVisibility}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Padding="5, 1" Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding AddScanVisibility}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="Add Missing Finisher" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="Small" />
            <Picker x:Name="pickerAboveBelow" Title="Pick" SelectedItem="{Binding AboveBelow}">
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>Above</x:String>
                    <x:String>Below</x:String>
                </Picker.Items>
            </Picker>
            <Entry x:Name="entryAboveBelowPosition" Text="{Binding AboveBelowPosition}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Placeholder="Pos" PlaceholderColor="Silver"  Keyboard="Numeric" WidthRequest="70" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            <Entry x:Name="entryMissingBib" Text="{Binding MissingBib}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Placeholder="Bib" PlaceholderColor="Silver"  Keyboard="Numeric" WidthRequest="70" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            <Button Command="{Binding MissingFinisherCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference entryMissingBib}" Image="addmanual.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Padding="5, 1" Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding AddScanVisibility}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Margin = "3" Text="Add Manual Time" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="Small" IsVisible="{Binding SubmitVisibility}"/>
            <Entry Margin = "3"  Text="{Binding AddHH}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Placeholder="HH" PlaceholderColor="Silver" IsVisible="{Binding SubmitVisibility}" Keyboard="Numeric" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            <Label Margin = "3"  Text=":" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="{Binding EndVisibility}" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            <Entry Margin = "3"  Text="{Binding AddMM}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Placeholder="MM" PlaceholderColor="Silver" IsVisible="{Binding SubmitVisibility}" Keyboard="Numeric" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            <Label Margin = "3"  Text=":" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="{Binding EndVisibility}" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            <Entry Margin = "3"  Text="{Binding AddSS}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Placeholder="SS" PlaceholderColor="Silver" IsVisible="{Binding SubmitVisibility}" Keyboard="Numeric" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding ManualTimeCommand}" IsVisible="{Binding SubmitVisibility}" Image="addmanual.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="End" Style="{StaticResource Buttons}" />
        </StackLayout>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Results}" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true"  IsVisible="true">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                <Label Text="{Binding ScanPosition}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="Red" />
                                <Button Image="trash.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding DeleteScanCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ScanId}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding FormattedName}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="0,0,0,5" FontSize="Large" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding EntryBibNumber}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,5" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Teal" />

                            <Label Text="{Binding FormattedClub}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0" FontSize="Small"  TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Category}"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0" FontSize="Small"  TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" />
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column = "3" Grid.RowSpan="3"  Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Elapsed}"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Start" />
                                <Button Image="trash.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding DeleteTimingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding TimingId}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="#f4da9e" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="3">
            <Button x:Name="buttonSubmitProvisional" Text="Publish Provisional"  IsVisible="true" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Command="{Binding DeleteScanCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
            <Button x:Name="buttonSubmitFinal" Text="Publish Final"  IsVisible="true" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechsportiseApp.API;
using TechsportiseApp.Views;
using TechsportiseApp.ViewModels;
using TechsportiseApp.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TechsportiseApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ResultsProcess : ContentPage
    {
        public ResultsProcess(Race race)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var viewModel = new ResultsProcessViewModel(race);
            BindingContext = viewModel;

            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Help", "help.png", async () =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ResultsProcessHelp());
            }, 0, 2));

        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel** (Some unimportant sections containig properties removed)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Input;
using TechsportiseApp.API;
using TechsportiseApp.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechsportiseApp.Helpers;

namespace TechsportiseApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ResultsProcessViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ICommand AddTimingCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddScanCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand DeleteTimingCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand DeleteScanCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand PublishProvisionalCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand PublishFinalCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand LoadResultsCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand MissingFinisherCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand MissingTimingCommand { get; set; }

        public int RaceId { get; set; }
        public DateTime RaceDate { get; set; }

        //public ResultsViewModel(Race race)
        public ResultsProcessViewModel(Race race)
        {
            AddTimingCommand = new Command(AddTiming);
            AddScanCommand = new Command(AddScan);
            DeleteTimingCommand = new Command<int>(DeleteTiming);
            DeleteScanCommand = new Command<int>(DeleteScan);
            PublishProvisionalCommand = new Command<int>(PublishProvisional);
            PublishFinalCommand = new Command<int>(PublishFinal);
            LoadResultsCommand = new Command<int>(LoadResults);
            MissingFinisherCommand = new Command<int>(MissingFinisher);
            MissingTimingCommand = new Command<int>(MissingTiming);

            Invalid = false;

            AddTimingVisibility = false;
            AddScanVisibility = false;
            AddVisibility = true;
            PublishProvisionalVisibility = false;
            PublishFinalVisibility = false;
            IsBusy = false;
            RaceId = race.Id;
            RaceDate = race.RaceDate;
            Scans = ScansAPI.GetScans(RaceId);
            Timings = TimingsAPI.GetTimings(RaceId);
            Entries = EntriesAPI.GetEntries(RaceId);
            LoadResults(RaceId);
        }



        ObservableCollection<Result> _results;
        public ObservableCollection<Result> Results
        {
            get
            {
                return _results;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_results != value)
                {
                    _results = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Results");
                }
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Scan> _scans;
        public ObservableCollection<Scan> Scans
        {
            get
            {
                return _scans;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_scans != value)
                {
                    _scans = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Scans");
                }
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Timing> _timings;
        public ObservableCollection<Timing> Timings
        {
            get
            {
                return _timings;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_timings != value)
                {
                    _timings = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Timings");
                }
            }

        }

        ObservableCollection<RaceEntry> _entries;
        public ObservableCollection<RaceEntry> Entries
        {
            get
            {
                return _entries;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_entries != value)
                {
                    _entries = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Entries");
                }
            }
        }

        bool _invalid;
        public bool Invalid
        {
            get { return _invalid; }
            set
            {
                if (_invalid == value)
                    return;

                _invalid = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Invalid");
            }
        }

        string _validationError;
        public string ValidationError
        {
            get { return _validationError; }
            set
            {
                if (_validationError == value)
                    return;

                _validationError = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ValidationError");
            }
        }

        string _errorMessage;
        public string ErrorMessage
        {
            get { return _errorMessage; }
            set
            {
                if (_errorMessage == value)
                    return;

                _errorMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ErrorMessage");
            }
        }

        public Race SelectedRace { get; set; }

        private bool _raceCountZero;
        public bool RaceCountZero
        {
            get { return _raceCountZero; }
            set
            {
                if (_raceCountZero == value)
                    return;

                _raceCountZero = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RaceCountZero");
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Race> _races;
        public ObservableCollection<Race> Races
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    var racelist = RacesAPI.GetRaces();
                    var sortedracelist = new ObservableCollection<Race>(racelist.OrderBy(c => c.Name));
                    var racecount = racelist.Count();
                    if (racecount == 0)
                    {
                        RaceCountZero = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RaceCountZero = false;
                    }

                    return racelist;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Invalid = true;
                    ValidationError = "Error getting Race List. No internet connection available.";
                }


                return _races;


            }
            set
            {
                if (_races != value)
                {
                    _races = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Races");
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }



        void AddTiming()
        {

            //Do stuff when adding a timing. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection



        }

        void AddScan()
        {

            //Do stuff when adding a timing. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection



        }

        void DeleteTiming(int timingid)
        {

            //Do stuff when deleting a timing. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = true);
                    var IsThereConnection = GlobalFunctions.CheckForInternetConnection();

                    if (IsThereConnection == false)
                        throw new Exception("You cannot delete a timing whilst you are offline");

                    //We are good to go
                    else
                    {
                        var deletetiming =  TimingsAPI.DeleteTiming(timingid);

                        if(deletetiming.Code != "200")
                            throw new Exception("Error deleting timing");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ValidationError = ex.Message;
                        Invalid = true;

                    });

                    return;
                }
                finally
                {                    
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Timings");
                }
            });


        }

        void DeleteScan(int scanid)
        {

            //Do stuff when deleting a scan. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = true);
                    var IsThereConnection = GlobalFunctions.CheckForInternetConnection();

                    if (IsThereConnection == false)
                        throw new Exception("You cannot delete a scan whilst you are offline");

                    //We are good to go
                    else
                    {
                        var deletetiming = TimingsAPI.DeleteTiming(scanid);

                        if (deletetiming.Code != "200")
                            throw new Exception("Error deleting scan");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ValidationError = ex.Message;
                        Invalid = true;

                    });

                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Scans");
                }
            });


        }

        void PublishProvisional(int raceid)
        {

            //Do stuff when submitting provisional. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection



        }

        void PublishFinal(int raceid)
        {

            //Do stuff when submitting final. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection



        }

        void MissingFinisher(int raceid)
        {




        }

        void MissingTiming(int raceid)
        {




        }

        void LoadResults(int raceid)
        {


            var results = new ObservableCollection<Result>();



                //Start with the timings
                foreach(Timing timing in Timings)
                {
                    var result = new Result();

                    //Basic details
                    result.RaceId = RaceId;
                    result.RaceDate = RaceDate;
                    result.Status = "Processing";

                    //Timing Data
                    result.TimingId = timing.Id;
                    result.TimingPosition = timing.Position;
                    result.TimingStatus = timing.Status;
                    result.StartTime = timing.StartTime;
                    result.EndTime = timing.EndTime;

                    var elapsed = result.EndTime - result.StartTime;

                    string elapsedhours = elapsed.Hours.ToString();
                    string elapsedminutes = elapsed.Minutes.ToString();
                    string elapsedseconds = elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
                    string elapsedmillis = elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString().Substring(0,2);

                    if (elapsedhours.Length==1) { elapsedhours = "0" + elapsedhours; }
                    if (elapsedminutes.Length == 1) { elapsedminutes = "0" + elapsedminutes; }
                    if (elapsedseconds.Length == 1) { elapsedseconds = "0" + elapsedseconds; }
                    if (elapsedmillis.Length == 1) { elapsedmillis = "0" + elapsedmillis; }

                    result.Elapsed = elapsedhours + ":" + elapsedminutes + ":" + elapsedseconds + "." + elapsedmillis;



                        results.Add(result);
                    }

                //Add in the scans
                foreach (Result result1 in results)
                {
                var scan = Scans.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Position == result1.TimingPosition);
                    if(scan != null)
                    {
                        result1.ScanId = scan.Id;
                        result1.ScanPosition = scan.Position;
                        result1.ScanStatus = scan.Status;
                        result1.ScanBibNumber = scan.BibNumber;       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result1.ScanId = 0;
                        result1.ScanPosition = 0;
                        result1.ScanStatus = 99;
                        result1.ScanBibNumber = "UNKNOWN";
                    }
                }

                //Add any scans which there are no times for (Higher than count)
                var timingscount = Timings.Count();
                var notimescans = new ObservableCollection<Scan>();
                foreach (Scan scan in Scans)
                {
                    if (scan.Position > timingscount)
                    {
                        var newresult = new Result();

                        newresult.RaceId = RaceId;
                        newresult.RaceDate = RaceDate;
                        newresult.Status = "Processing";
                        newresult.ScanId = scan.Id;
                        newresult.ScanPosition = scan.Position;
                        newresult.ScanStatus = scan.Status;
                        newresult.ScanBibNumber = scan.BibNumber;

                        newresult.TimingId = 0;
                        newresult.TimingPosition = 99999;
                        newresult.TimingStatus = 99;
                        newresult.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                        newresult.EndTime = newresult.StartTime;

                        var elapsed = newresult.EndTime - newresult.StartTime;

                        string elapsedhours = elapsed.Hours.ToString();
                        string elapsedminutes = elapsed.Minutes.ToString();
                        string elapsedseconds = elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
                        string elapsedmillis = elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString();

                        newresult.Elapsed = elapsedhours + ":" + elapsedminutes + ":" + elapsedseconds + ":" + elapsedmillis;


                        results.Add(newresult);
                    }
                }

                //Then add in the entries
                foreach (Result result2 in results)
                {

                    var entry = Entries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.BibNumber == result2.ScanBibNumber);
                    if (entry != null)
                    {
                        result2.EntryId = entry.Id;
                        result2.FirstName = entry.FirstName;
                        result2.LastName = entry.LastName;
                        result2.FormattedName = entry.FirstName + " " + entry.LastName.ToUpper();
                        result2.Gender = entry.Gender;
                        result2.DateOfBirth = entry.DateOfBirth;
                        result2.Club = entry.Club;
                        result2.Team = entry.Team;
                        result2.EntryBibNumber = entry.BibNumber;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result2.EntryId = 0;
                        result2.FirstName = "Unknown";
                        result2.LastName = "ATHLETE";
                        result2.Gender = "Unknown";
                        result2.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;
                        result2.Club = "";
                        result2.Team = "";
                        result2.EntryBibNumber = "Unknown";
                    }

                }
            var sortedresults = new ObservableCollection<Result>(results.OrderBy(c => c.TimingPosition));
            Results = sortedresults;


        }



    }
}
```

Comment: the buttons are contained in a ListView, so by default their binding will be relative to the individual element of the list, which is Result.  Your commands are defined on the base viewmodel.  You'll need to use a reference binding - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646037/xamarin-forms-binding-button-command-to-parent-bindingcontext

Comment: Bang on thanks Jason.